# Слушатель нажатия listView. Как при нажатии на категорию переходить в список ее представителейю

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста, работаю над создание приложения для занятий спортом.
мне необходимо при нажатии на фрагмент меню "Упражнения!, что бы выводились категории мышц, далее при нажатии на категорию что бы выводился список упражнений и при нажатии на упражнение его описание.
Сделала следующее, в обработчики нажатия на фрагмент меню "Упражнения" у меня выводится список упражнений из моего array. Элементы заполняются в listView, далее я создала класс Text_Content_Activity в котором объявила массив с описанием упражнений и массив с картинками, там и передаю номер категории и позиции.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private ListView list;
private String[] array;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private int category_index;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fish_array);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(array)));
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //toolbar.setTitle(R.string.fish); //Заголовок при открытии

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Text_Content_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("category",category_index);
            intent.putExtra("position",position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.fish);
    return true;
```

}

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    int id = menuItem.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id.id_fish)
    {
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.fish);
        array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fish_array);
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.addAll(array); //добавляем польностью array
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //команда об изменении array
        category_index = 0;
    }
    else if(id == R.id.nav_gallery)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Молодец, ты нажала", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        category_index = 1;
    }
    else if(id == R.id.nav_slideshow)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Молодец, ты нажала", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        category_index = 0;
    }
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

**Text_Content_Activity**

```
public class Text_Content_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView text_content;
private ImageView iContent;
private int category = 0;
private int position = 0;
private int [] array_fish = {R.string.fish_1, R.string.fish_2, R.string.fish_3};
private int [] array_image = {R.drawable.ryka, R.drawable.press, R.drawable.spina};

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.text_content);
    init();
    reciveIntent();
}
private void  reciveIntent()
{
    Intent i = getIntent();
    if(i != null)
    {

        category = i.getIntExtra("category",0);
        position = i.getIntExtra("position",0);
    }
    //переключатель категории
    switch (category)
    {
        case 0:
            iContent.setImageResource(array_image[position]);
            text_content.setText(array_fish[position]);
            break;
    }
}

private void init()
{
    text_content = findViewById(R.id.text_main_content);
    iContent = findViewById(R.id.image_content);
}
```

}

Мне нужно теперь сделать промежуточный этап. Что бы при нажатии у меня не сразу выходил список упражнений, а вначале список с категориями (шея, бицепс и т.д) и при нажатии на эту категорию уже список упражнений из нее.
Как это можно реализовать? Так же добавить перечень категорий в array и нажатие проверять в слушателе нажатия listView, если это так то приведите пожалуйста пример или как еще можно поступить.

Пока наброски приложения выглядят так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если вы только в начале пути, откажитесь от использования Drawer'а и используйте нижний NavigationBar для навигации по приложению

Answer (score 0):

Разобралась, в слушателе нажатий на listView необходимо так же заполнить адаптер новыми данными, как и в нажатии на фрагмент меню, т.е

```
array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ex_array);
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.addAll(array); //добавляем польностью array
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //команда об изменении array
            category_index = 0;
```

Только наименование string-array нужно сменить.